# How to keep $FrontEnd options from resetting?

Tags: front-end, initialization

I'm trying to get *Mathematica* to look in a different, version-tracked folder for the 'TextResources' files that it uses to build the Front End. I've prepended my version-tracked folder path to the `$FrontEnd` option `PrivatePaths`, both from the Options Inspector and using SetOptions. Both of these methods make *Mathematica* use my version-tracked files the next time I restart the Front End, but it quickly reverts to the versions at `$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows` within one or two Front End restarts.

I'm not certain what triggers this switch back to the default directory, but I'd really like to stop it from happening so that I can reliably and persistently use my customized, version-tracked instances of the 'TextResources' files. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: You can put appropriate files in `$UserBaseDirectory` instead of editing system files. Then you can start different versions of *Mathematica* with different `$UserBaseDirectory` by setting MATHEMATICA_BASE and/or MATHEMATICA_USERBASE enviromental variables depending on your OS.

Comment: @ybeltukov He doesn't appear to be editing system files. He refers to having his own version tracked files.

Comment: I am indeed editing the files in *Mathematica*'s 'TextResources' folder, but as Mike said above, I want to place my edited versions in a separate folder and load those versions preferentially over the ones in *Mathematica*'s default 'TextResources' folder.

Comment: @bdot yes that is the way I read your question. On OS X I have not noticed an issue but I only did a couple of restarts. Maybe when i have more time I can test more fully.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks for helping out by trying to recreate the issue on your machine. I'm not certain that it's restarting the Front End that resets the `PrivatePaths` Option; I'll do some more systematic testing to see if I can figure out precisely what action is responsible for resetting the $FrontEnd Options. Do let me know if you have any thoughts on the issue. Thanks!